# Attendance Calculations / Period Calendar

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slice

This is a multi-tiered project. Let me give a quick overview. I have attendance data, card/ timestamp punches. I would like to have a pivot table with slicers in Excel. Ideally you'd be able to choose a department / last name / associate number. And also a period of time. Ideally this would be a table with the company period/week. And maybe default to last weeks.

I can get at timecard data in two ways:

(1) generate a CSV that automatically performs the timecard math, to figure out how many hours someone worked and it is smart enough to understand 3rd shift workers. The format of that CSV is:

> Last Name, First Name, Personnel Type, Associate Number, Facility, Department, TimeIn, TimeOut, Total Hours

The problem with this method is that I would have to manually append the information to the CSV tables. Or come up with some autoIT script.

(2) Get at the raw data via sql/odbc. This way the math is not done. It is just all of the associates timestamps. I would have to figure up the daily hours myself and figure out a 3rd shift formula too. It is not a set schedule, many people swing shifts and others get called in a lot.

Lastly, I would like to be able to filter the dates by using our company fiscal calendar. I have a spreadsheet that goes from 2000 to 2093. With everyday listed and it's corresponding year/period/week.

Example period info spreadsheet:

```
date    Year    Period  week    WeekTotal   Period Total
12/3/2007   2008    1   1   2008.1.1    2008.1
12/4/2007   2008    1   1   2008.1.1    2008.1
```

I know there is a lot going on here, but what would be the best way to approach this project?

Answer (score 0):

First I have not been able to post any script however the last I tried it I used two options 1. Was a php conversion where the time was numbers ( which makes it easier for calculations)
2. Was in the tables where I deliberately entered the values places the time in different columns or fields for hours, mins, and seconds this meant that while the input is eased I still have to calculate the output in php especially for totals, averages and differences.
Hope it helps a bit